# mysql stored procedure execute priveleges - not able to connect

Tags: php, mysql, privileges

Trying to connect from PHP with:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", 'user', 'password', "db");
```

Set up privileges on the database with:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE db.test TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

I'm sure I'm missing something basic. Would appreciate help

Comment: Sorry, the problem is I'm getting the error **Access denied for user**

Comment: BTW. Works fine with root credentials.

Comment: I'm closing this question as no-reproduction, since the OP self-answer the question with "Likely an install issue on os x... thanks" (now deleted).